# Giving a meaningful name to Dockerfile's VOLUME

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In Dockerfile we can use `VOLUME /some/folder` to let docker always create a volume for the specified folder when calling `docker run`, without having to explicitly use the `-v` parameter. The volume created will have a random (unreadable) alphanumerical name.

**Question:** is it possible to specify a readable name for the volume on container creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not specify a volume source when you define a volume in an image. Doing so would be a potential security exploit where an image could mount a private volume with a common name and send the contents of that volume over the network. To create your volumes with known names, and have that defined in a file, you would do that at runtime with a docker-compose.yml file when the container is created. E.g.

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  - app_data
services:
  app:
    image: your_image:1.0
    volumes:
      - app_data:/data
```